# Is there a way to transform my for loop into an sapply function?

Tags: r, loops

Assuming I have a df with many rows and taking the head of the data frame.

```
df<-structure(list(time = c(270, 330, 270, 250, 280, 500), who = 1:6, 
    x = c(987.353265152362, 570.817987386894, 1147.5681499552, 
    637.526076016409, 1439.13510253106, 1396.6452808061), y = c(1802.08232812874, 
    349.336242713164, 1789.49467712533, 361.611973188148, 1492.44148360367, 
    1459.91771610835), metricrel = c(2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 2.011, 
    2.011, 2.011), sim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a loop that runs through each time in the above data frame and compares it to a given time. This is represented by samp.time. Once those times are collected basic summary functions are used to give the total number of infected and the mean of the infected, translating into prevalence.

```
for (sim in unique(df$sim)){ ## looping over simulations
  #print(paste("For ",sim))
  stti<-sample(1:10,1)
  infmax<-max(df$time)
  samp.time <- seq(from = stti, to = infmax, by = 10) 
  ## for ease we make a temporary dataframe of the current simulation
  temp <- df[df$sim==sim,]
  ## we sample n=20 hosts
  ## loop over the sampling times
  for (t in samp.time){##here you see that the hosts sampled is after the loop detecting
    ##time that hosts are detected as infected, thus changing every time you update the sampling
    test <- sample(temp$who, 20,replace=FALSE)
    #print(paste("Id",test))
    
    ## get those hosts infection time
    inf.time <- temp[temp$who %in% test, "time"]
    #print(paste("at time",inf.time))
    ## if an infection time is anterior to the sampling time, we have a detection event
    m <- sum(inf.time <= t) ## we sum to know how many host are seen as infected
    ## we can also measure the true incidence at sampling time
    q <- mean(temp$time<=t)
    ## and increment the result table in the loop
    res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t))
    if (m>=1){
      break
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to translate this code into a sapply function. Would it be possible to do so? I am thinking that I can somehow create a function and then create a data frame of the desired outputs, I am thinking that is will look something like this:

```
sample_strat<-function(n,r){
  res<-NULL
infmax<-max(df$time)
  stti<-sample(1:r,1)
  samp.time <- seq(from = stti, to = infmax, by = r)
  for (t in samp.time){
    test <- sample(df$who,n,replace = FALSE) 
    inf.time<-df[df$who %in% test, "time"]
    m <-sum(inf.time <= t)
    q<-mean(df$time<=t)
    res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t))
    if (m>=1){
      break
    }
  } 
  }
  

df %>% group_by(sim) %>%
  do(data.frame(sim=sim, m=sapply(df, sample_strat(20,10))$m,q=sapply(df, sample_strat(20,10))$q,t=t)
```

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do use `sapply`? Both are loops. Of course, using sapply has a benefit for more concise and readable code. I'm not sure that's the case, though! Open for feedback.

Comment: Hi eduardokapp, the reason being is that I am using the parallel package, and this loop is producing NULL as the output. I am trying to convert this to sapply so that I can test if this fixes the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. At least based on your dataframe provided, `sample(temp$who, 20,replace=FALSE)` throws an error, because you have replace = FALSE but the length of temp$who on iteration 6 is less than 20.